# SQLite query still slow after indexing and different read methods

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, unity-game-engine, ado

**Context:** The database stores books and has three columns: *call number*, *title*, *width*. I have a virtual, infinitely scrolling bookshelf in Unity which acts almost like a buffer into this db, displaying books in ascending order by call number for the range it currently represents.

**Problem:** My query becomes slow when accessing data records not previously accessed, so I want to find a way to optimize it. For example, when I first scroll right, new shelves take unacceptably long to load (it fetches the next 'x' books from the db), but if I scroll right, then back left, when I scroll right again it's almost instant. I think SQLite is caching results in some way.

**Implementation:**
My query is constructed like this:

```
var query = string.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM testing " +
    "WHERE call > '{0}' " +
    "ORDER BY call ASC " +
    "LIMIT {1}",
    startCallNum, count);
```

and is meant to return the next `count` records when sorted in ascending call number starting from a call number `startCallNum`.

The data base has an index for the *call number* column.

I've tried both the DataReader and DataTable approach to getting the results back, but both run into equal performance issues:

DataReader:

```
var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = query;
var reader = command.ExecuteReader()

while (reader.Read()) {
    var entry = new DataEntry();
    entry.CallNum = reader.GetString(0);
    entry.Title = reader.GetString(1);
    entry.Width = reader.GetDouble(2);
    results.Add(entry)
}
```

Data Table:

```
var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = query;
var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult)

var table = new DataTable();
table.Load(reader);

var callCol = table.Columns["call"];
var titleCol = table.Columns["title"];
var widthCol = table.Columns["width"];

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var entry = new DataEntry
    {
        CallNum = (string) row[callCol],
        Title = (string) row[titleCol],
        Width = Convert.ToDouble(row[widthCol])
    };
    results.Add(entry);
}
```

The connection is kept alive for the duration of the program and is stored in the `_connection` member.

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query.

Comment: `string.Format` => Possible SQL Injection. How do you sanitize input?